# How to get only specific field from the list

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, list, ienumerable

I have an IEnumerable of Lesson objects:

```
IEnumerable<Lesson> filteredLessons
```

I convert it to a List through the following method:

```
ToList();
```

But I want the returned list to contain only the first property, `lessonid`, not all the `Lesson` properties.

How can I get the data of specific property of the list instead of the objects?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can select the value you want first, like this:

```
filteredLessons.Select(l => l.lessonId).ToList();
```

And you'll get a list of ID's

Comment: Any suggestions on how best to make this solution work generically for any property?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the the specific row value from list using linq use the following code:

```
var name = from r in objClientList
           where r.ClientCode == Convert.ToInt32(drpClientsInternal.Items[i].Value)
           select r.IsInternalClient;

foreach (bool c in name)
{
    if (c)
    {
        ClientNameInternal = ClientNameInternal + drpClientsInternal.Items[i].Text +", ";
        drpClientsInternal.Items[i].Selected = true;
    }
}
```